# How did Antoine get to the sea in the The 400 Blows (Les Quatre Cents Coups)?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-400-blows

In the final scenes of [*The 400 Blows (Les Quatre Cents Coups)*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0053198/), we see Antoine run to the sea having escaped from his detention center. However, before, when René comes to see him, he takes a bike and they both live in Paris.

There are lots of plausible explanations (René stealing a bike, Antoine not doing the entire distance at once) but none of them are particularly satisfying. **Is there a better explanation**?

Comment: Note that it is about 100 miles / 160 km from Paris to the shore near Honfleur / Le Havre.